# C++ structure containing a RTTI getter function?

Tags: binary-analysis, c++, ghidra, struct

I'm working on reversing a C++ application and I've come across a structure that contains a getter function that returns `TypeDescriptor*`, I've read some articles on RTTI and reversing C++ but can't find a structure that matches what I'm seeing.

It *seems* to be a compiler generated structure because of the `TypeDescriptor` getter? I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. There's multiple of these structures, they are in mostly contiguous but not completely as far as I can see.

Pseudo code for the struct looks like:

```
// These are all function pointers
class SomeClazz
{
    // func1/func2 are pointers to the same function. It looks like a constructor.
    void* func1(void* param1, void** param2);
    void* func2(void* param1, void** param2);
    // This function differs depending on the class. I believe this to be a implementation of a virtual function maybe?
    virtual void handler();
    // Returns a pointer to a RTTI TypeDescriptor depending on the class
    TypeDescriptor* get_type_descriptor();
    void get_something();
}
```

Here's code in the `func1/2` functions in case there's a hint of what it is:

```
undefined ** FUN_00125860(longlong param_1,undefined **param_2)

{
  undefined4 uVar1;
  undefined4 uVar2;
  undefined4 uVar3;
  
  *param_2 = (undefined *)&Vftable_maybe_00589ef0;
  uVar1 = *(undefined4 *)(param_1 + 0xc);
  uVar2 = *(undefined4 *)(param_1 + 0x10);
  uVar3 = *(undefined4 *)(param_1 + 0x14);
  *(undefined4 *)(param_2 + 1) = *(undefined4 *)(param_1 + 8);
  *(undefined4 *)((longlong)param_2 + 0xc) = uVar1;
  *(undefined4 *)(param_2 + 2) = uVar2;
  *(undefined4 *)((longlong)param_2 + 0x14) = uVar3;
  return param_2;
}
```

Here's `get_type_descriptor`:

```
TypeDescriptor * class::get_type_descriptor(void)

{
  return &class_<lambda_88a0d3301c644a20c1df3ad0c52a86e4>_RTTI_Type_Descriptor;
}

////////////
LEA RAX, [class_<lambda_88a0d3301c644a20c1df3ad0c52 ...]
RET
```

Here's `get_something`, not sure what the purpose is or what it's doing:

```
LEA RAX, [RCX+0x8]
RET
```

Any help/suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter. Grep for `typeid` in MSVC `<memory>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lambda expression. When the lambda expression has captures it is compiled into a implementation defined structure. In my case the lambda has captures, using MSVC the structure was [`_Func_Base`](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/1e8b8d4eef4b2dddeb7533c5231c876383bd0ea6/stl/inc/functional#L775-L801) defined as:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable : 4265) // class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual (/Wall)
// CLASS TEMPLATE _Func_base
template <class _Rx, class... _Types>
class __declspec(novtable) _Func_base { // abstract base for implementation types
public:
    virtual _Func_base* _Copy(void*) const                 = 0;
    virtual _Func_base* _Move(void*) noexcept              = 0;
    virtual _Rx _Do_call(_Types&&...)                      = 0;
    virtual const type_info& _Target_type() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void _Delete_this(bool) noexcept               = 0;

#if _HAS_STATIC_RTTI
    const void* _Target(const type_info& _Info) const noexcept {
        return _Target_type() == _Info ? _Get() : nullptr;
    }
#endif // _HAS_STATIC_RTTI

    _Func_base()                  = default;
    _Func_base(const _Func_base&) = delete;
    _Func_base& operator=(const _Func_base&) = delete;
    // dtor non-virtual due to _Delete_this()

private:
    virtual const void* _Get() const noexcept = 0;
};
#pragma warning(pop)
```

Answer (score 3):

IIRC the [`typeid` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) returns a pointer to a type info instance.

Overall the code looks like a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) implementation; the “constructor” captures the context so that the “handler” (lambda body) can access the variables it needs from the outer scope.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe impossible from what I've provided but any chance you could provide some pseudo code of how you imagine it might have looked? I haven't had much luck trying to recreate this in code.

Also thank you for your amazing RTTI article.